# How to deal with file names which contain spaces in Ruby(In Git Bash)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, bash

I encounter a problem about running some Git commands which contain white spaces in file names with Ruby, like:

```
aaa = "xxxxxxx/xxxx/BOM\ Explosion.txt"

`git update-index --assume-unchanged -- #{aaa}`
```

or

```
aaa = "xxxxxxx/xxxx/BOM Explosion.txt".shellescape

`git update-index --assume-unchanged -- #{aaa}`
```

I have tried either way above to escape space and run it in Git Bash, but neither of them work, with the error message:

```
fatal: Unable to mark file 'xxxxxxx/xxxx/BOM
Updated git index
```

Anyone have some ideas?

Comment: have to tried quoting them e.g. `git update-index --assume-unchanged -- "'#{aaa}'"` this will translate to `git update-index --assume-unchanged -- 'xxxxxxx/xxxx/BOM Explosion.txt'` which should work

Comment: The `shellescape` function is what's supposed to handle this. Thing is, how are you actually executing this command? Can you add that part to your question?

Comment: @tadman it's actually written, but it's not indented with spaces as Markdown requires. I tried to edit it, but SO complained that I should at least change 6 characters. Apparently whitespace doesn't count. In essence, **in this code commands are executed with backticks (`)**.

Comment: If the first of your examples, escaping is wrong, because unescaping will be done by Ruby first, and then by Bash. You will get a literal space in your string, while you need a literal **backslash** and then space. In Ruby syntax that is accomplished by using **two backslashes and then a space** (`"like\\ so"`). However, `shellescape` is the way to go, so it's just a note.

Comment: How are you running these commands? Backticks? `system`?

Answer (score 2):

You can largely ignore escaping concerns if you specify parameters individually:

```
system("git", "update-index", "--assume-unchanged", "--", aaa)
```

This passes the arguments through directly without the shell interpreting them. This is the most reliable way to pass them through correctly.

Comment: That's what i do. I always try to keep the shell out of the picture when executing external programs. Also probably a good idea to use the full pathname to git.

Comment: The most reliable and the only sane way to use `system`. And if you can't use `system`, use `Open3`.

Comment: Yeah, `Open3` is great if you care more about the specific output of the command than just the result code which is all you get from `system`.

Comment: Thanks. system() can execute command line in a subshell which avoid spaces problem. Also, quoting the variable would work as well.